# Как образом можно вывести такую структуру?

Tags: php

Есть такая структура

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-left">
    <div class="point"></div>
    <div class="point"></div>
    <div class="point"></div>
    <div class="point"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-right">
    <div class="point"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <div class="item-left">
      <div class="point"></div>
      <div class="point"></div>
      <div class="point"></div>
      <div class="point"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-right">
      <div class="point"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Есть массив который имеет 30 пунктов, каждую надо вывести в point. Наверху идет цикл foreach. Каким образом можно вывести по такому принципу что бы каждые 5 пунктов размещались в item-left а один в item-right 
Спасибо

Comment: я так понимаю классы `item-left` / `item-right` предназначены для выравнивания на `float`? Если да, то можно самому `item` задать `display: flex;`

Comment: там больше дело в их размерах ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как-то так и сделать. Если задача не понятно как решается целиком, то разделите ее на части. В данном случае, она довольно просто решается, если  разделить на фрагменты по 5 элементов. А дальше отделять из пятерки последний и выводить отдельно.

```
$items = range(1,30);
$chunks = array_chunk($items, 5);

foreach($chunks as $c){
   //item
   $last = array_pop($c);

   foreach($c as $item){
       echo "left - $item\n";
   }
   echo "right - $last\n";
}
```

получите

```
left - 1
left - 2
left - 3
left - 4
right - 5
left - 6
left - 7
left - 8
left - 9
right - 10
....
```

Comment: Просто офигительный метод, спасибо